# Marshaling a class to a byte[] occasionally throws a (sometimes) un-catchable AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, marshalling, access-violation

I'm beginning to believe I'm missing something pretty fundamental with the .Net marshal capability.

The situation is that I have C# application(s) that need to inter-operate with existing C++ applications without modifying the C++ inter-process protocol.  The C++ applications pass structures between processes using serialization that is literally a memory snapshot of the structure.

I frequently have to (un)marshal these objects to/from tcp or multicast streams.

What I've found is that 99.95% of the time everything is just great, but at other times, but every so often, I'll get an AccessViolationException and that, even less often, the standard mechanism of catching them fails, generally in Client GUI (as opposed to server) processes.

Below is one helper-method I've created to aid in marshaling a class to a byte buffer for transmission.

I don't understand why this would ever generate an access violation as the structs (actually class in this case) are simple classes that, at most, implement an interface or two, with no inheritance involved.

I'm more confused as to why the exception sometimes sneaks out when the application is running from a local drive.

Any ideas as to what's wrong here?

For reference:  VS 2010, .Net 4.0.

```
    [System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
    public static Tuple<byte[], bool> MarshalClass<T>(T theClass) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            int aSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
            byte[] aBuffer = new byte[aSize];

            IntPtr aBuffPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(aSize);

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(theClass, aBuffPtr, false);
            Marshal.Copy(aBuffPtr, aBuffer, 0, aSize);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(aBuffPtr);

            return new Tuple<byte[], bool>(aBuffer, true);
        }
        catch (System.AccessViolationException)
        {
            return new Tuple<byte[], bool>(null, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can't catch that kind of exception, for good reasons, as your memory might be corrupt at that point.

Comment: This code also has a memory leak. You should have a `try-finally` block immediately after the call to `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`, and have the call to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()` in the `finally`.  Otherwise if an exception is thrown by `Marshal.StructureToPtr()` or `Marshal.Copy()`, you'll not be able to release the memory you allocated.

Comment: Further, on inspection, you're using `Marshal.StructureToPtr()` to marshal a `class` not a `struct`.  It's possible that the mismatch is causing the size of the class for marshalling to not match what you expect its behaviour to be.  You may need to investigate the use of the `[StructLayout]` and `[MarshalAs]` attributes on the objects you are trying to marshal.

Comment: 1) You can catch that kind of exception as long as your code is trusted and the attributes listed are applied to the method.  Except that sometimes (rarely) it doesn't catch.

Comment: Good catch on the memory leak.  I'll fix that.

Comment: As far as `[StructLayout]` and `[MarshalAs]`, I have all classes involved set to `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` and I specify `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 48+1)]` for string fields.

Comment: Better yet, use a C++/CLI project instead.